# Is there any way to horizontally flip my monitor?

Tags: display, display-settings

I have an ATI 3200 MRadeon, graphics card, and I wanted to know if there is any way to horizontally flip, or "mirror" my monitor. Is it possible to do this from within Catalyst Control Center (Ati's settings program) or is there a third party software I would be able to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a rotation setting in the Catalyst driver or software. You may need to enable an "advanced" mode in order to view e setting but there should be an option rotate 90 degrees.

Comment: I think Sean meant flipping the screen literally as in a mirror, so that text goes from right to left and all...

Comment: Yes, Cerberus is correct: not, rotate, but flip. I am trying to set up this cheapy little DIY projector, and all the words are backwards and upside down. I flipped the Monitor 180°, but the words are still backwards.

Comment: It looks like there is an Nvidia program called NVKeystone, http://www.nvidia.com/object/feature_nvkeystone.html, that will do it.

You can see it in action in the video linked here: http://diyprojectorkits.com/beginners-area/2096-need-software-flip-monitor-image-horizontally.html#post17336

Still looking for a comparable ATI solution.

Comment: http://khaid.drue.us/mirror/pvcmirror.zip
I found this here: http://journal.pcvsconsole.com/?thread=7650 I downloaded it and it worked on my laptop running Windows 7. To cancel it, just open task manager and close the pvc mirror program. It works for me but I guarantee nothing. Good luck!

Comment: hmm.. When you tried moving the mouse around or anything, did it just disappear for you, because that is what is happening to me?

Comment: The mouse works fine for me. There are some drawing issues on the flipped Windows Explorer windows but the mouse works fine for me.

Comment: What happens is if I anything on the screen moves, it will change it back to regular, instead of flipped.

Comment: I don't know. It worked for me. I don't know anything about it, I just found it on a google search. There's the NVidia program that will do it but I didn't find anything for ATI video cards. Perhaps contact ATI and see if they know of anything that is compatible with their cards.

Comment: k, well thanks. Just wondering, what OS are you running, Im on win7 32-bit

Comment: I'm on the same. Running a Lenovo T61 so I don't have a beefy graphics card.