# flip monitor in windows 10 using on-board means

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I want to mirror my screen. Not only duplicating it, I look into the screen through a mirror.

I use Nvidia graphics card which can only flip around the horizontal axis. It cannot clone a display while flipping it. Nvidia confirms this limitation.

I know there is a tool called UltraMon. But it looks like it is not maintained anymore. It has issues when the computer goes to standby. It's also an expensive solution when you use several computers.

So how can I flip a screen in Windows? I suspect I need registry entries. Presumably in
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration`

I found two related questions but they do not provide an answer and they date pre-W10.

- [Is there any way to horizontally flip my monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/233039/is-there-any-way-to-horizontally-flip-my-monitor)
- [How can I horizontally flip/invert my monitor (not rotate)?](https://superuser.com/questions/554589/how-can-i-horizontally-flip-invert-my-monitor-not-rotate)

Comment: Have you seen the other suggestions at https://telepromptermirror.com/mirror-flip-screen/ ?

Comment: I was unaware of the site but I knew most solutions. The HDMI hardware adapter costs 500$+Shipping. Linux and MAC are not an option in an enterprise setting.

Comment: Could you use MS Windows subsystem for Linux, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about ? Also, since LCD's are transparent, could the screen be removed from backlight and flipped?

Comment: The plastic housing of the display will almost certainly break if I try to open it. Not to mention that I would loose warranty too. Why do that if there would be a simple registry entry to achieve the same? I like Linux. It runs on all my servers. But I will not recommend it for my wife's laptop.

Comment: I ended up buying a monitor that can flip its image in the settings (hardware).